# right click nstextview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am implementing a customized editor. I am using NSTextView.  In doing so, I am using a spell checker to check the word and give back suggestions. I want to be able to add the word to the context menu. This is similar to Text Edit.

My question is when the user right clicks on a word, TextEdit seems to highlight the entire word. How can I achieve a similar functionality. I want to pass the selected word to the spellchecker and get the result back. I don't want the user to select the word. But instead just right click in the middle of a word and highlight the entire word for him.

Comment: Are you using a custom spellchecker or the system standard? NSTextView automatically does that with the system spellchecker.

Comment: @Wekwa - I am using shared NSSpellChecker but I am clearing the context menu for my editor and adding a new context menu.